# modified date filter in batch script?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a Batch script that is doing exactly what I want it to, would just like to have it running all the time, but in order to do so need to make sure the files it's selecting aren't in use.  Easiest way to do that is to say if the modified date hasn't changed in 3 hours it's good.  So I have this call:

```
for %%f in ("d:\recorded tv\*.wtv") do (
 REM do stuff
)
```

Any idea how to modify the above to say give me everything that is a WTV extension in the Recorded TV folder and that hasn't been modified in at least 3 hours?

Thanks.

JR

Comment: How can you be sure that the file isn't in use based on the last modified time? Surely that just tells you when it was last saved, not whether it's open with modification!

Comment: Good question.  And the answer is I can't.  Unless I can physically tell that from a command prompt, best I can do is assume no show would record for more than 3 hours and if someone is using it well such is life.  Don't think with my solution of a DOS batch file any solution is perfect but at least reduces chance of a file in use.

Comment: If a file has been modified, the file system sets the archive attribute on the file. If you need to know if a file is in use, you can use the openfiles command. Also, user dbenham wrote a pure batch solution to lock files and to see when a file is in use. Search SO to find it.

Comment: Why not simply trying to access the file do the action only in case of success, meaning the file is free and not in use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long ago I've wrote a [script that can filters the files by their times](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/FileTimeFilterJS.bat). Though it is not extensively tested you can try it:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('
  FileTimeFilterJS.bat "d:\recorded tv\" -hh -3 -direction before -filetime accessed ^|
  find /i ".wtv"
') do (
  REM do stuff with %%#
 )
```

Comment: Sorry deleted the comment to late.  I found that stack included some html in the copy and went away when I fixed it.  Thanks for the code.  I ran it thru and couple things.  I think this is basically returning everything in the directory.  Returning files from yesterday.  Also I didn't mention this, but is there a way to keep it from being recursive?

Comment: @John - try to alter `-direction before` to `-direction after` then.

Comment: @John - you can add `-recursive yes` or `-recursive no` depending on what you want.

Comment: Actually I think the opposite was right.  To many files and I am looking for things that have been untouched for over 3 hours.  Need to test a bit more to verify with a smaller dataset.  Any thoughts on the recursion?