# forfiles for specific datetime

Tags: datetime, batch-file, for-loop, forfiles

I am trying to list files that were modified after certain datetime. For instance, `june 8 20:29`, but I am having trouble finding these options for forfiles.
Do you know if datetime option is available for forfiles or I should use something different?
my batch file is below.

```
NET USE b: /DELETE
NET USE b: "\\networkddrive\users\username" /PERSISTENT:YES
CHCP 1252 > NULL
forfiles /p b:\ /s /m *.txt /d +"06/08/2018 14:22" /c "cmd /c echo @path @fdate @ftime"  > "b:\listfiles.txt"
```

Comment: `ForFiles` can only filter on the date, not the time.

Comment: See if this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49887455/1417694) suits your needs.

Comment: Hint: Never use the drive letters `A:` and `B:` for something other than real floppy drives. The usage of those two letters for network resources, USB storage medias or hard disks can easily result in unexpected behavior because of `cmd.exe` and Windows kernel handles in some cases file system accesses different on `A:` and `B:` even if the drive is not really a floppy drive.

Comment: `CHCP 1252 > NULL` redirects output of `%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com` on changing the code page to Windows-1252 to __file__ *NULL* created in current directory if that is possible instead of suppressing this output by redirecting it to device `NUL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forfiles` will not deal with the time part, only with the date.
I suggest using a Powershell script:

```
param (
[string]$ds=((Get-Date).AddDays(-10)).ToString()
)

$dt=(Get-Date $ds)
Get-ChildItem -Path "B:\" -Filter "*.txt" | Where {($_.LastWriteTime -ge $dt)} | Sort-Object LastWriteTime,Name
```

Store this script in a *.ps1 file to run it. The (optional) parameter is a string which can be interpreted as a date, like "1.4.2017 17:00". The arbitrary default is 'now minus 10 days'.